# Is it possible to reference comma separated values using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, reference

I have to following XML-Document:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>foo,bar,baz,qux</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

The value I'd like to get is the third element of the comma separated values of the element `<C>` (in the example above I'd expect `baz`)

Is there a way to reference it? e.g.:

```
  A/B/C/substring-after(,{2})/substring-before(,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that xpath do not have this capability.

If you are using java then you can do something like this:-

```
 String OSNAMES= Driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH")).getAttribute("value");
 String[] parts = OSNAMES.split(",");
 String OS = parts[2];
 int a=Integer.parseInt(OS);
 System.out.println(a);
```

Hope it will help you :)